# how to retrieve the administration account in ubuntu

Tags: update-manager

I am using ubuntu,yesterday i change username in my user account but now administration account locked,guest account opened,now i want my administration account how  to retrieve the account i tried some other way but i am getting unable to change to root gid: Operation not permitted.My Ubuntu Version 14.04.3

Comment: How did you change your username?

Comment: setting/user-acounts/it wil be there

Comment: Changing your username locked you out of your account?

Comment: yes,now how to delete this guest account

Comment: Can you specify your version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release: 14.04
Codename: trusty

Answer (score 0):

1. Start the terminal.
2. run `gksu gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`
3. Change the `allow-guest=true` to `allow-guest=false`
4. Save the file.
5. reboot your computer.

Your guest account should now disappear.

Comment: Possible to retrieve the account on terminal way

Comment: You mean like on a different run-level post the splash screen?

Comment: From what I understood from your question, you don't have access to your root account right?

Comment: I access to my root account,but don't want that guest account how to delete???

Comment: Ah, you want to remove the guest account? Check my answer, I've updated it.

Comment: Now i am getting like this The program 'gksu' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
How to intall gksu????